# Finding a subspace of P3: the set of all polynomials p(x) in P3 where p(0)=0.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I am lost on this.  I believe it is a subspace of Polynomials of degree 3.

What I have done.

addition:

u and v are vectors of the form $a(0)^3=0;$ so so $u+v=0$  closed

scalar multiplication:

$c$ is some scalar, so $c*u= c*a(0)^3 =c*0=0$; closed

not-empty(this is where I am unsure):

$P(0)=0$ is the 0 polynomial so I feel like this is implied that it is closed.

$$a(0)^3 + b(0)^2 + c0 + 0=0 $$

Can anyone confirm if I have this understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. One note: the term *closed* refers to a set being *closed* under some operation. The last claim you made that $0 \in P_3$ is correct, but has nothing to do with $P_3$ being *closed*...

Comment: These are three conditions that must be checked, but even the argument for addition is a bit confused. A general element of $P_3$ has the form $a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$, not just $a x^3$. In this case, we don't even need the general form, just that polynomial addition is linear: If polynomials $p, q$ are in the subspace, then $(p + q)(0) = p(0) + q(0) = 0 + 0 = 0$.

Comment: @gt6989b thanks! And there was a second part to the question that was the set of all polynomials of degree 2.  This too would be a subspace because of course polynomials of degree 2 are included in the set of polynomials of degree 3.

Comment: @chamburger That only implies that the set of all polynomials of degree $2$ is a subset, not a subspace. In fact, since $\deg 0 \neq 2$, it is /not/ a subspace.

Comment: @chamburger please see my answer.

Comment: @Travis this was a separate part of a question it was completely: Which of the following are subspaces of P3? a) The set of all polynomials of degree 2.  b) The set of all polynomials p(x) in P3 satisfying p(0) = 0.  From my understanding of subspaces they both are subspaces.  My professor used the term closed as in closed under scalar multiplication and closed under vector addition, but it also has to include the zero vector at least thats what i thought.

Comment: My comment gave a proof of the fact that the set of polynomials of degree $2$ is /not/ a subspace of $P_3$---simply, it doesn't contain the zero vector in $P_3$.

Comment: @Travis I'm confused can't we say that a polynomial of degree 2 could be of the form a(0)^2 + b(0) +0=0? thats a degree 2 polynomial. Is this not allowed?

Comment: That expression is the evaluation of a particular polynomial at $x = 0$. I think what you mean is that the space of polynomials of the form $a x^2 + b x + c$ is a subspace of $P_3$. /That/ statement is true, but not all polynomials of that form have degree $2$, only those with $a \neq 0$ do.

Comment: @Travis ah I see what you are saying, so if we have any poly of degree 2 where a = 0 and we check it under scalar multiplication we will not get a degree 2 poly in return.

Comment: @chamburger Yes, in fact all three conditions fail, as $x^2$ and $-x^2$ both have degree $2$ but $x^2 + (-x^2) = 0$ does not.

Comment: @Travis for completeness, on checking the last condition that it contains the 0 vector how would you prove it fails?  Like whats the correct approach.  Thanks.

Comment: By convention, one usually sets the degree of the zero polynomial to $-\infty$, which has various advantages. But the important thing is simply that $\deg 0 \neq 2$. Of course, one only needs to show that one condition fails to prove that it isn't a subspace.

Comment: @Travis thanks I appreciate your help. a 0 polynomial will always produce a 0 which is not a degree 2 polynomial.

Comment: Yes, that's right, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second question that set $P_2$ in $P_3$ is a subspace cannot be dealt with as you write in the comment - just because they are included, does not mean they are a subspace. (consider for example a set of all polynomials with odd leading coefficients - it is clearly not a subspace).

But you could deal with it in exactly the same way. Multiplying any polynomial of 2nd degree by a constant will yield a polynomial of at most 2nd degree, and so too, adding a pair of 2nd degree polynomials. Thus, $P_2$ is closed under addition and constant multiplication and also $0 \in P_2$, hence $P_2$ is a subspace of $P_3$ as well...

If you mean to look at the set of *just* degree 2 polynomials, it is not closed under constant multiplication, since multiplying it by a constant $0$ will not yield a 2nd degree polynomial...

Comment: I posted the exact question as it was written in my text book.  It was a 2 part question based on finding subspaces of P3.  a) The set of all polynomials of degree 2. b) The set of all polynomials p(x) in P3 satisfying p(0) = 0.